# Why can't "traceroute -i en0"/connectx/equivalent bypass Cisco AnyConnect VPN on Mac?

Tags: mac, vpn, cisco-anyconnect

I have the Cisco AnyConnect VPN (SSL-based) installed on my Mac (Ventura). When the VPN is active, I am trying to see if I can bypass the VPN when making network connections. I have tried two high-level approaches:

- Explicitly choose the en0 (wifi) interface (rather than the VPN's utun interface). E.g., `traceroute` command with "`-i en0`" option, the `connectx` API, etc
- Use `route` command to set en0 as the chosen interface for a particular destination.
  Neither of the above approaches work.

With the former (explicitly choose the en0 interface): The connection never completes. `traceroute` times out on each hop. And the `connectx` call times out as well. Wireshark shows no packets being sent out on any interface.

With the `route` command, I see the command itself seemingly succeeds (ie it exits with 0 status), but the changes to the routing table don't stick. i.e., `netstat -r` shows effectively the same results as it did earlier.

Any idea as to the reasons for the above? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the routing table doesn't stick"? Anyway, if the creator of the VPN server didn't want you working around it, you won't be able to do it.

Comment: I meant "changes to the routing table don't stick", made the edit on the question as well. Re "if the creator of the VPN server didn't want you working around it, you won't be able to do it": note here my changes are entirely on the client. Want to know how my attempted changes are being negated.

Comment: The Cisco driver takes care of the routing table.